# Why is array.push overriding the entire array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, interface, request

I send a get request to the api wichh returns data under form of

```
{
"message": "<SUCCESS>",
"result": [
{
  "i": 1,
},
{
  "i": 2,
},    
{
  "i": 3,
}  ]
}
```

Then in javascript (angular component.ts) I want to create an array ob objects but after pushing the objects in the array every array contains the data of the last object:

```
.subscribe(
          data => {
            type MyArrayType = Array<UserOpinion>;
            let array: MyArrayType = [];
            let cont: CustomInterface = {
              i: ''
            }

            data.result.forEach(function(entry) {
            cont.i = entry["i"];

            array.push(cont);
            console.log(cont);
            //right value is shown

            })
            //console.log(array)
            //array contains the connect number of objects but the objects are set on the             same value: "i" = 3
```

Any ideas why this happens? Thank you

Comment: Because there is only 1 `cont`.  You need to make a new object within the `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you zero! Which syntax should I use?

Comment: just move your `let cont` declaration to INSIDE the `forEach` rather than before it

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked

Comment: *"Then in javascript (angular component.ts) I want to create an array ob objects"* but you already have an array of objects: `let array: UserOpinion[] = data.result;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
        type MyArrayType = Array<UserOpinion>;
        let array: MyArrayType = [];

        data.result.forEach(function(entry) {
            array.push(entry);
        });
    }
);
```

You dont need `cont` just for copying the current object to another, you can use the current loop element directly.